# Please why am I losing child association data when ecto changeset insert fails?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I have a Client schema that belongs to a User schema, and has one Company schema (optional).

Here is the Client changeset I'm using with a registration form :

```
  @doc false
  def create_changeset(%Client{} = client, attrs) do
    client
    |> cast(attrs, [:qualification, :phone])
    |> cast_assoc(:user, with: &User.create_changeset/2)
    |> cast_assoc(:company)
    |> validate_required([:qualification])
    |> unique_constraint(:user_id)
  end
```

And now here is a Context function that creates a User, Client and Company all at once.

```
def create_client(attrs \\ %{}) do
  %Client{}
  |> Client.create_changeset(attrs)
  |> Repo.insert()
end
```

When all required data and their validation are ok on the registration form submit, the insertion succeeds and everything goes as I hope. Even when form validation fails before insertion attempt, the registration form is rendered back with all errors and populated with previously sent data...

But when insertion fails on a User database constraint (for example an already taken email) , the form is rendered back with all data and errors only for User and Client schema. All Company data are lost. This will force the client to re-enter all his Company information.
Is this behaviour unavoidable?

In case it could be useful, I'm using Phauxth library for user authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create company independently of the client, consider using [alternatives for cast_assoc](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3-alternatives-to-cast_assoc-3).

I don't know exactly your use case, but it looks like you want to create a company if client's data are fine and regardless of user data. Maybe you can call each `changeset` for each schema explicitly without casting it in the `Client.changeset`.

Also, your client doesn't need to send you again the `attr`, as you already have them - even if `Repo.insert` fails, you have access to `changeset.params`, so you can use them with some additional logic.

Comment: Thank you as you suggested, I'm finally able to restore Company changeset using changeset.params. Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(changeset, :company, Company.changeset(%Company{},
    changeset.params["company"] || %{}))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding each parameter manually, you can merge your changeset errors with the changeset from before you perform the database operation:

```
def create(conn, %{"client" => client}) do
  changes = Client.changeset(%Client{}, client)
  case Repo.insert(changes) do
    {:ok, _} -> ...
    {:error, errors} ->
      changes = Ecto.Changeset.merge(changes, errors)
      render(conn, "new.html", changes: changes)
  end
end
```

Note that the order of the changesets matters. The second changeset takes precedence over the first<sup>1</sup> so the errors will override any existing fields.

---

<sup>1</sup> https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#merge/2